# HTTP upload using WinInet

Tags: http

I'm doing http(PUT) upload using WinInet library, on WinXP its working fine but on Win7 its not working and the strange thing is 'InterWriteFile' function of WinInet files is returning true. Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks in Advance.

```
//this is the first function that is called when upload is requested.
void Upload()
{
//check if handle is already open or not
    if(!m_hNetOpen)
    {
    //open interconnect: Initializes an application's use of the WinINet functions.
        m_hNetOpen = InternetOpen("XYZ", 
            INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            INTERNET_INVALID_PORT_NUMBER);  

        //return if handle is NULL
        if(m_hNetOpen == NULL)
        {
            return FALSE;
        }   
    }                                                                        

    //we'll get user specified URL, could be some xyz.com too. 
    if(!m_hNetConnect)
    {
    //opens HTTP or FTP connection for a site requested...pchServerName requested
        m_hNetConnect = InternetConnect(m_hNetOpen, 
            strServerName, 
            INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP,
            INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE,
            dwContext);  
        //return if handle is NULL
        if(m_hNetConnect == NULL)
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }    

    dwContext = 0;
    //now, create HTTP request
    m_hHttpConnect = HttpOpenRequest(m_hNetConnect,
        "PUT",
        strObjectName,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        INTERNET_FLAG_CACHE_IF_NET_FAIL,
        dwContext);  
    //return if handle is NULL
    if(m_hHttpConnect == NULL)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }    

    //call UseHttpSendReqEx
    BOOL bRet = UseHttpSendReqEx(m_hHttpConnect, strUploadFileName);  

//if not suuceeded log the message
    if(!bRet)
    {
        //Logmessage
    }  
    if(m_hHttpConnect)
    {
        //close the handle
        InternetCloseHandle(m_hHttpConnect);
    }    

    return bRet;
}

//this function is will send HTTP request and writes data to internetfile
BOOL UseHttpSendReqEx(HINTERNET hConnect, char *upFile)
{
    INTERNET_BUFFERS BufferIn = {0};
    DWORD dwBytesRead = 0;
    DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;
  //buffer
    BYTE strBuffer[20480] = {0};
    BOOL bRead;
    BOOL bRet = TRUE;  

    //get the size of structure
    BufferIn.dwStructSize = sizeof(INTERNET_BUFFERS);  

    //create file
    m_hFile = CreateFile(upFile, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
        NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

    //check for invalid handle
    if (m_hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)  
    {
        return FALSE;
    }  

    //get the file size
    BufferIn.dwBufferTotal = GetFileSize(m_hFile, NULL);  

    //send request to HTTP server
    if(!HttpSendRequestEx(hConnect, &BufferIn, NULL, HSR_INITIATE, 0))
    {
        //close the file handle
        CloseHandle(m_hFile);
        m_hFile = NULL;
        return FALSE;
    }  

    DWORD sum = 0;
    do
    {
        //read the file that is to be uploaded
        if (!(bRead = ReadFile(m_hFile, strBuffer, sizeof(strBuffer),
            &dwBytesRead, NULL)))
        {
            bRet = FALSE;
            break;
        }  

        //write the internet file
        bRet=InternetWriteFile(hConnect, strBuffer, dwBytesRead,
            &dwBytesWritten);  

        if(!bRet)
        {
            DWORD d = GetLastError();
            bRet = FALSE;
            break;
        }
        memset(strBuffer, '\0', sizeof(strBuffer));
        sum += dwBytesWritten;
    }
    while(dwBytesRead == sizeof(strBuffer)) ;

    //This sleep was introduced as if we immediately after the above loop
    //if we try to close the handle then file does not get created on the   server  
    Sleep(100);
    BOOL b = CloseHandle(m_hFile);
    m_hFile = NULL;  

    return bRet;
}
```

Comment: [WhatHaveYouDone.com](http://www.whathaveyoudone.com) - please post your code

Comment: hey for some reasons i'm not able to post my code...can you please give me your mailid.
Thank You.

Comment: No, visit: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: I have posted my code....please see to it. Thanks